# LernaJS Typescript cannot find module

Tags: node.js, typescript, lerna

I'm trying to use LernaJS with typescript and I have some problems. When I try to run my package-1 which has package-2 as dependency I get the error:

```
    module.js:549
        throw err;
        ^
    
    Error: Cannot find module 'package-2'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object. (/home/gabriel/Documentos/projetos/nodejs/lerna-t2/packages/package-1/dist/index.js:3:19)
        at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I've followed the following steps:

1. I've created a directory and ran the command 'lerna init'
2. I've created 2 folders inside (package-1, package-2) 'packages' folder

```
    .
    ├── lerna.json
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package.json
    ├── package-lock.json
    └── packages
        ├── package-1
        └── package-2
```

3. I've ran 'npm init' in both (package-1, package-2)
4. I've created a basic 'tsconfig.json' in both packages:

```
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "outDir": "dist",
            "target": "es5",
            "module": "commonjs"
        }
    }
```

5. I've ran 'lerna bootstrap' in the root folder
6. I've use 'lerna add package-2 --scope=package-1'
7. I've ran also 'npm i' in root folder, package-1 and package-2
8. I've ran 'tsc -w' in package-1 and package-2 and 'node dist/index.js' in package-1

**FILE TREE**

My 'package-1' file tree:

```
    .
    ├── dist
    │   └── index.js
    ├── index.ts
    ├── node_modules
    │   ├── package-2 -> ../../package-2
    │   └── typescript
    ├── package.json
    ├── package-lock.json
    └── tsconfig.json
```

My 'package-2' file tree:

```
    .
    ├── dist
    │   ├── index.js
    │   └── lib
    │       └── teste.js
    ├── index.ts
    ├── lib
    │   └── teste.ts
    ├── package.json
    ├── package-lock.json
    └── tsconfig.json
```

**CODE**

**package-1**:

- index.ts:

```
    import { Teste } from 'package-2'
    
    new Teste().printHello()
```

**package-2**:

- lib/teste.ts:

```
    export class Teste {
    
        printHello() {
            console.log('Hello!')
        }
    
    }
```

- index.ts:

```
    export { Teste } from './lib/teste'
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Please ensure you have defined `main` in your package.json in (at least project-2). I assume the name field in package.json (for project-2) is `project-2`.

Main should link to `dist/index.js`

Comment: @lajtmaN: Please elaborate, what does it do and how do you come to this resolution?

Comment: @Gegenwind That is how Lerna links the projects together. When you import another project from the Lerna repository, you are actually just importing whatever is defined in `main` in the package.json. 
AFAIK it is not possible to link directly to your index.ts file since the compiler expects the imported files to be compiled already. That's why you should use the compiled javascript file (often located in a folder named dist or build).

Comment: Thank you very much, a very small detail I was missing :)

Comment: @lajtmaN please explain what you mean by "Main should link to dist/index.js". I ask because I already defined main in all package.json files and still have this error.