# LernaJS TypeScript Monorepo issue exporting files from a package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, nestjs, lerna

I have an Lerna Monorepo project that contains a frontend (React-CRA) and a backend (NestJS).
The problem i'm having looks like this issue: [LernaJS Typescript cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50780112/lernajs-typescript-cannot-find-module)

There is one package in my project called 'shared' for Types and consts that i want to use in both systems.

When i try to import a const from React, it works ok, i can access its properties, but when i try to import from NestJS, i get the same error from the issue above:

```
 module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@my-project/shared'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object. (/home/gabriel/Documentos/projetos/nodejs/lerna-t2/packages/package-1/dist/index.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I have tried set a main entry point with a .tsconfig file watching for changes, but i can only import Interfaces and Types from this package inside NestJS App.

Import TypeScript files (interface and types [*i get errors when importing Enums!*]) works in both systems

[Shared Package Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZiDk.png)
[Shared *package.json*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcijN.png)

Comment: i don't think Monorepo is used this way. to me, it'll normally mean lots of independent repo siting under a folder. Otherwise, i don't know how you deal with the compilation issue, because most of the build will monitor a folder.