# LernaJs tsc Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, typescript, lerna

I am creating a full-stack monorepo project using lerna.

In one of the sub-project I got `Cannot find module '@gepick/database/connect'`.

my lerna.json

```
{
  "packages": ["packages/*", "projects/**"],
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "useWorkspaces": true,
  "npmClient": "yarn"
}
```

my gepick/database/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@gepick/database",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.11",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mongodb-client-encryption": "^1.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.9"
  }
}
```

node based subproject package.json

```
{
  "name": "scripts-api-football",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start:collectDayMatches:dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node -r source-map-support/register build/collectDayMatches.js\"",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19",
    "tsc-watch": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@gepick/database": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "commander": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

node based subproject tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "lib": ["es2016", "esnext.asynciterable", "webworker"],
    "types": ["node"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "utils/*": ["./utils/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["tests", "tasks"]
}
```

main package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gepick-lerna",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start:front-web": "lerna run start --scope front-web --stream",
    "bootstrap": "lerna bootstrap",
    "build:scripts:api-football": "lerna run build --scope scripts-api-football --stream",
    "start:scripts:api-football:start:collectDayMatches:dev": "lerna run start:collectDayMatches:dev --stream"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.20.2",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "projects/**",
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.27.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.27.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

---

Also, I tried to add `main: "connect.js"` to `@gepick/datebase` package.json file. But looks like `@gepick/datebase` package don`t have compiled js. Maybe it is issue (tsc not compiles library files) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LernaJS Typescript cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50780112/lernajs-typescript-cannot-find-module)

Comment: see if `lerna bootstrap` solves ur probem

Comment: I tried to add main option to package.json. Also, I tried run lerna bootsrap from root folder. But app still don`t find model. But maybe problem is that tsc not compile lerna package at all, and it is the reason why can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that packages were not compiled to js. I changed `node` to `ts-node` for run script. Now it works.